# SASS imports don't work with gulp-ruby-sass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, gulp

I've tried to setup a project described like [here](http://markgoodyear.com/2014/01/getting-started-with-gulp/) Everything works fine, but SASS imports don't work.

The **main.scss**:

```
@import
  "partials/0.mixins",
  "partials/1.settings",
  "partials/2.normalize",
  "partials/3.base",
  "partials/4.layout",
  "partials/5.typo",
  "partials/6.states",
  "partials/7.theme",
  "partials/8.print";
```

**gulp** produces the following **main.css**:

```
@import
  "partials/0.mixins",
  "partials/1.settings",
  "partials/2.normalize",
  "partials/3.base",
  "partials/4.layout",
  "partials/5.typo",
  "partials/6.states",
  "partials/7.theme",
  "partials/8.print";
```

and **main.min.css** is empty. I've tried to use the `loadPath` flag in my gulpfile.js without success ;( My task config:

```
...
// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/styles/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        check: true,
        loadPath: 'src/styles',
        style: 'expanded'
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
...
```

My resources are from a Compass/SASS project and with grunt it works.

Any suggestions?

Thanks & ciao
Ralf

Comment: you could try `gulp-compass` instead, that one worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the option `check: true`, which, [as the documentation states](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass#check), tells the task to "Just check syntax, don't evaluate." Give it a try without `check: true`.

Comment: You are right. In my projects I use gulp-ruby-sass now. And without `check: true` there are no problems with sass partials. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brian for your tip. With **gulp-compass** it works.

Here is my **gulpfile.js**:

```
// Load plugins
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    compass = require('gulp-compass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    lr = require('tiny-lr'),
    server = lr();

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/styles/main.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
        sass: 'src/styles',
        css: 'dist/styles'
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});

// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});

// Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/images/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Images task complete' }));
});

// Clean
gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return gulp.src(['dist/styles', 'dist/scripts', 'dist/images'], {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.start('styles', 'scripts', 'images');
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Listen on port 35729
  server.listen(35729, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    // Watch .scss files
    gulp.watch('src/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);

    // Watch .js files
    gulp.watch('src/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);

    // Watch image files
    gulp.watch('src/images/**/*', ['images']);

  });

});
```

Thanks a lot.

Ciao
Ralf